# MySQL "Error Code 1305: SAVEPOINT a does not exist"

Tags: mysql, rollback

I just started learning MySQL and I just got introduced to savepoints and rollbacks.

I did this:

```
START TRANSACTION;

CREATE TABLE test (
    c1 int,
    c2 varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('1', 'LINHA1');

SAVEPOINT A;

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('2', 'LINHA2');

ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT A;
```

**When I run "rollback to savepoint A", it says "SAVEPOINT a does not exist".**

Comment: Are you sure the table is an INNODB table

Comment: yes I am sure it's an INNODB table

Comment: The CREATE TABLE command ends the transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In mysql, DDL (such as CREATE TABLE) can't be inside a transaction.  Your CREATE TABLE is ending your transaction, and every statement thereafter is auto-committed, so there is no savepoint A by the time you do the ROLLBACK.